# R ggplot scale_alpha_gradient with a centered scale

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a custom scale for alpha that has opacity peak at the center of the scale, and fade away at either end. I was thinking I could map a custom alpha scale to the data, but I would like to keep a legend that maps the transparency to the original values (it would also be a challenge to split the positive and negative values each with a share of the zeros to two separate unit vectors?).

Example where I would like Sepal.With of 0 to have alpha=1, fading to both 4 and -4 having alpha=0.01

```r
dt = data.table(iris)[,Sepal.Width := ifelse(.I %% 2 == 0, Sepal.Width, -Sepal.Width)]

ggplot(dt, aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Petal.Length, color=Species)) + 
  geom_point(aes(alpha=Sepal.Width), size=3, stroke=0) + 
  scale_alpha_continuous(range=c(0,1)) + 
  scale_color_brewer(palette="Dark2", direction=1) + 
  theme_classic()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a custom continuous scale with whatever palette function that accepts input between [0, 1]. You can use the `rescaler` argument to set a rescaler function that will center at 0.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(data.table)

dt = data.table(iris)[,Sepal.Width := ifelse(.I %% 2 == 0, Sepal.Width, -Sepal.Width)]

ggplot(dt, aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Petal.Length, color=Species)) + 
  geom_point(aes(alpha=Sepal.Width), size=3, stroke=0) + 
  continuous_scale(
    "alpha", "my_scale",
    palette = function(x) abs(1 - abs(x - 0.5)* 2),
    rescaler = ~ scales::rescale_mid(.x, mid = 0)
  ) +
  scale_color_brewer(palette="Dark2", direction=1) + 
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-03-29 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>